# Using ListIterator to get the Next and Previous elements from the Current element of the List

Tags: java, spring, list, iterator

I have list of element for that I have to match some specified element and get the previous and next for that element.

The problem here is when you do `iterator.next()` or `iterator.prev()` it returns the same element because the cursor is moved back and forth returning to the same element. So what I did is I use `previousIndex()` and `nextIndex()` method to get only index and retrieve element from the list from that index.

Also make sure to do decrement from previous index as cursor is moved to next element so current element will be returned.

```
for (final ListIterator<Xyz> iterator =  nodeList.listIterator();iterator.hasNext();){
            if(iterator.next().equals(midString.get())) {
                final Xyz prev=nodeList.get(iterator.previousIndex()-1);
                final Xyz next= nodeList.get(iterator.nextIndex());
                return some condition true;
            }
        }
```

Wanted to know is there any better approach to achieve same or any improvements in existing solution.

Comment: why not use simple `for` loop with `indexes`?

Comment: Use iterator.previous() twice to go back to the element

Comment: @SivaRahul wouldn't it change the current iteration position?

Comment: Since you need both the previous value and the next value, use iterator.previous() first and iterator.next() twice to get the values and be in the same position.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to process *previous*, *current* and *next* nodes at each iteration step, you can simply define a couple local variables before the loop.

The idea of utilizing `ListIterator` will not improve the readability, conversely to make the `ListIterator` approach working you have to introduce a lot of redundancy because each call of `next()` or `previous()` advances the iterator, and it'll also cause unnecessary performance overhead.

That's how it can be done by maintaining two variables for *previous* and *current* nodes.

```
public static boolean processNodes(List<Node> nodeList) {
    if (nodeList.size() < 3) return false;

    Node prev = nodeList.get(0); // previous node
    Node cur = nodeList.get(1);  // current node
    
    for (int i = 2; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
        Node next = nodeList.get(i); // next node
        
        if (cur.equals(something) && someSondition(prev, next)) {
            return true; // or introduce a flag (before the loop), set the flag to true and break from the loop
        }
        prev = cur; // reassigning nodes
        cur = next;
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

I would also suggest introducing a `boolean` flag initialized to `false` and change it value to `true` in the loop, rather than returning from the middle of the method.

```
public static boolean processNodes(List<Node> nodeList) {
    boolean result = false;
    
    if (nodeList.size() < 3) return result;
    
    Node prev = nodeList.get(0); // previous node
    Node cur = nodeList.get(1);  // current node
    
    for (int i = 2; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
        Node next = nodeList.get(i); // next node
        
        if (cur.equals(something) && someSondition(prev, next)) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
        prev = cur; // reassigning nodes
        cur = next;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```